# Как добавить кастомные поля в checkout wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу добавить на страницу checkout дату доставки. Поэтому в вёрстку я добавил нужный инпут. Как теперь это поле передавать в информаицю о заказе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить поле

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_fields' );
 
function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    
       $fields['billing']['date_delivery'] = array(
                                                           'type' => 'text', 
                                                           'label' => __('Дата поставки', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN),
                                                           'required' => false
                                                       );
       return $fields;
}
```

Сохранить при отправке заказа

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'update_checkout_order_meta');

function update_checkout_order_meta( $order_id ) {
           if ( ! empty( $_POST['date_delivery'] ) ) {
              update_post_meta( $order_id, 'date_delivery', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['date_delivery'] ) );
           }      
    
        }
```

Вывести поле в подробностях заказа

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'custom_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function custom_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
           if(get_post_meta( $order->id, 'date_delivery', true )){echo '<p><strong>'.__('Дата поставки', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN).':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'date_delivery', true ) . '</p>';}
}
}
```